# Значение из input1 сделать ссылкой которая переходит на тот сайт который указан в input2

Tags: javascript, html

Есть страница с input1 text (напишется название которое должно отобразится на 2 странице) и input2 text (пишется ссылка на сайт). и button. Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на button произошел переход на вторую страницу на которой отобразилось значение из input1 и также это значение стало ссылкой которая переходит на тот сайт который указан в input2.

Пример index1.html:

```
<input type="text" id="firstInput"  value="" placeholder="Фамилия Имя Отчество">
<input type="text" id="firstInput"  value="" placeholder="Ссылка на Сайт">
<button id="submitButton" onclick="document.location='index2.html'">Присоединяйся</button>   
    
    <script>
        let btn = document.getElementById("submitButton");

        btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            val = document.getElementById("firstInput").value;
            localStorage.setItem("inputValue", val);
        });
    </script>
```

Index2.html

```
     <form action="index.html">
    <input type="button" id='input'>
    </form>

    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function() {
            val = localStorage.getItem("inputValue");
            localStorage.removeItem("inputValue");
            document.getElementById("input").value = val;
        })
         window.addEventListener("unload", function() {
            localStorage.setItem("inputValue", document.getElementById("input").value);
        })

    </script>
```

Comment: Хранилище localStorage привязана к источнику (домену, протоколу и порту). Данные, находящиеся в некотором источнике, доступны только на страницах этого же источника. К данным другого источника обратиться нельзя. Насколько я понимаю, при открытии страниц на локальном сервере будет доступ к localStorage из другой страницы. Просто так доступа не будет.

Answer (score 0):

В таком виде, используя, например, Live Server в Visual Studio Code, можно передавать значения инпута со страницы на страницу. А вот фраза "Значение из input1 сделать ссылкой которая переходит на тот сайт который указан в input2" ставит в тупик, честно говоря. Если вопрос был о чем-то другом, разъясните более детально.

index1.html

```
<html>
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    <input type="text" id="firstInput"  value="" placeholder="Фамилия Имя Отчество">
    
    <button id="submitButton" onclick="document.location='index2.html'">Гоу туда</button>   
    
    <script>
            let val = localStorage.getItem("inputValue");
            console.log('bbbb', val);
            document.getElementById("firstInput").value = val; 

        let btn = document.getElementById("submitButton");
        btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
           let val = document.getElementById("firstInput").value; 
           localStorage.setItem("inputValue", val);
            console.log('aaaaaa', val, localStorage.getItem("inputValue"));
        });
    </script>

    
</html>
```

index2.html

```
<html>
    BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

      <input type="text" id="firstInput"  value="" placeholder="Фамилия Имя Отчество">
      <button id="submitButton" onclick="document.location='index1.html'">Гоу обратно</button>
  
      <script>

              let val = localStorage.getItem("inputValue");
              console.log('bbbb', val);
              document.getElementById("firstInput").value = val; 

              let btn = document.getElementById("submitButton");
              btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                let val = document.getElementById("firstInput").value; 
                localStorage.setItem("inputValue", val);
                  console.log('bbbbb', val, localStorage.getItem("inputValue"));
              });
  
      </script>
    
</html>
```